# How to get Facebook like button's comment list

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Now our requirement like this:

We have a like button on one page, user can click that like button and type comment in the popup comment box.

Question is how to get all the comment of like button of specified page? We want to show all these comments in another place of this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We have a like button on one page, user can click that like button and type comment in the popup comment box.

If the user types a comment into the box popping up when using the like button, the result is *not* a comment, but a *link share* of the URL – so that’s an individual post on that user’s wall.

I had a little look around the FQL tables, but I did not find anything that would give you the resulting post without knowing the actual user who used the like button.